# Application freezes when I try to draw on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, timer, jpanel, paintcomponent

I have two JPanels:

```
public class FirstPanel extends JPanel
public class SecondPanel extends JPanel implements Listener

FirstPanel.addListener(SecondPanel)
SecondPanel.setPanel(FirstPanel)
```

`Listener` is an interface that has a single method `update()`.

The SecondPanel has a middleLeftPanel where I want to place the FirstPanel:

```
DesignUtils.addComponentAndConstraints(middleLeftPanel, FirstPanel, DesignUtils.createGridBagConstraint(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, null));
```

I also have a number of iterations (ex: 10000) and after each iteration, the FirstPanel repaints itself and updates listeners, in this case only SecondPanel:

```
public void trainStepPerformed(...) {
    repaint(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    updateListeners();
}
```

SecondPanel's `update()` method:

```
this.validate();
this.repaint();
```

When I press a JButton on the SecondPanel I want to see how the FirstPanel paints itself on the middleLeftPanel from SecondPanel at every iteration but instead the application freezes and when the last iteration is done It unblocks and shows me only the final result. I tried to use SwingUtilities.InvokeAndWait but it throws an exception.

I also tried using swing Timers, maybe I don't know how to use them exactly by this is how I used the timer:

In the constructor of FirstPanel I initialized the Timer:

```
timer = new Timer(1, new MyActionListener());

public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            repaint(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            updateListeners();
        }
    }
```

FirstPanel has a method called trainStepPerformed (which is called for every iteration to draw the new panel) which before using the Timers had the same code as actionPerformed from MyActionListener class, now:

```
@Override
    public void trainStepPerformed(...) {
        timer.start();
```

Because repaint calls paintComponent I thought this is the place where to stop the timer:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    %rest of the code%

    timer.stop();
}
```

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: 1) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix. 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: .. 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks you for all your tips. I am here to learn, of course. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely blocking the Swing thread. Try to offload your heavy processing to [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

Comment: Using it I will see every step of the painting process during the number of iterations?

Comment: @user1849859 Yes, if you remember to call `panel.revalidate();` at the end of each iteration.